# C# - Blocking a folder from being changed while processing

Tags: c#, .net

I have a single-threaded program that processes folders and files in a source directory.  Is there a way to block a folder, with files in it, within my source directory from being modified by other processes while my program is working on it?  I'm thinking something along the lines of placing some kind of exclusive lock on the folder itself, so only my program's process can use it.

NOTE:

I do not want to block the root source directory itself, just whatever folder(s), in the top level of that directory, I might be processing at any particular moment.  I still want to be able to allow outside processes to add folders to the source directory, while I'm processing other folders.

UPDATE:

@Yuri - Yes this is a Windows program, a Windows Service application to be exact.

Part of what makes this both challenging and necessary is that I need to recreate the structure of whatever folder(s) I'm processing, in the source directory, in a separate destination directory.  So I can't have a any other process modifying the folder(s) and File(s) while my program is working with them.

Comment: I wonder if the new I/O transaction methods could help.

Comment: Instead of locking the folder, your program could just scan through the contents a second time to be sure that there have been no external changes since you started (checking file names and dates)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ways to lock a folder:

1.Mark it readonly. (Included because people always try this)
Con - **This does not actually work.**  On folders, the readonly flag is used for other purposes.

2.Mark all of the contents readonly.
Con - Won't prevent certain types of actions (e.g., creating new items).

3.Use ACL
Con - Won't prevent administrators from messing with the folder.  Requires certain types of permissions.

4.Use ACL with a specially created user and enable folder Encryption.
Con - This is really of horrifying.  If anything goes wrong, your data might be lost.

5.Rename/Move the folder
Con - Can be bypassed by user stupidity.

6.**(Edit)** gjvdkamp's answer: [Lock Individual files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692981/c-blocking-a-folder-from-being-changed-while-processing/4693064#4693064)
Con - As with #2, this still allows creating new files *within* the folders.  That said, this is *The Right Way™* to do it.

Comment: Hi Brian, ACLs may work to.  Leaving only the admins capable of messing with a folder and it's contents may not be a big issue in my case as long as I know that no one or nothing else can mess with it.

Comment: @kingrichard: Fair enough.  Personally, I run my Dev IDE as administrator because some of my projects run as admin, so this wouldn't work for me at all.

Comment: @gjvdkamp: Well, I noticed my answer had more votes/attention than yours, probably because you posted code about 2 hours after I posted my answer.  It did not strike me as ideal that the best way to solve the problem (best way in general; it *might* not be the best way for the OP) was not the top answer.

Answer (score 7):

*edit* don't us this hack, doesn't work:
http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/folder-lock/

Else i would loop over all files in foder, create a `list<FileStream>` and then call Lock on each. This would give you finer grained control over wich files to lock.

GJ

Edit: Try something along these lines:

```
var locks = new List<FileStream>();
var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");
foreach (var file in di.GetFiles()) {
    var fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open);
    fs.Lock(0, 0);
    locks.Add(fs);
}
```

Comment: I think the hack only stops Explorer from accessing the folder. But locking each individual file would be my recommendation.

Comment: Haven't tried that hack, but I like your second idea, since I'm already collecting files from the folder(s) I'm processing.  In that case, how would I add a lock to each file in the list?

Comment: +1 : This is much cleaner than using readonly as I was thinking, and the locks are naturally released even if the program crashes, unlike with my solution.

Comment: @Brian - thank you Brian, I'm currently occupied with other tasks, but I will try this approach.  Too bad a locking mechanism like this doesn't exist for directorys, that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help you http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/Unique_Folder_Protection.aspx

What the article basically does is change the extension of the folder to one of the following

".{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}"
".{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
".{2559a1f4-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}"
".{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}"
".{2559a1f1-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}"
".{7007ACC7-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}"

And stores the password inside the folder

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: This only prevents access via the Explorer shell. It is still possible to access the folder through the command line, and presumably other methods involving the direct path (e.g. other programs). Of course, it also renames the folder, which could lead to a read error if something expects the folder to be there but does not stop anything from actually writing there.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a new copy of the folder, work on that one then replace the old one if neccessary?

Comment: Because if another service worked on that folder, those actions would be thrown away.

Comment: True, its a compromise. But what other options are there: dodgy hacks and setting readonly.

Comment: A similar compromise which avoids this issue is to rename the folder, though this also means programs that just want to *read* the folder can't do so either.