# How to synchronize handling of filesystemwatcher events?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, filesystemwatcher

I have the following synchronization problem.

A thread runs in a loop and if it detects a folder in filesystem which was not processed yet (it may have been added while the app was not running), the folder is processed as a new folder by `Process` method:

```
void Loop()
{
 while (run)
 {
  lock(renameLock)
  {
    var newFolders = EnumerateNewFolders().ExceptThoseMarkedAsRenamed();
    Process(newFolders);
    MarkAsProcessed(newFolders);
  }
  Sleep();
 }
}
```

Renamed folders should not be processed as new but rather processed as renamed and marked as renamed so that they are not processed as new later.

To take care of this, I have a `FileSystemWatcher` and a handler for the `Renamed` event:

```
private void fsw_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
  lock(renameLock)
  {
    ProcessRename(e);
    //mark folder as renamed so that ExceptThoseMarkedAsRenamed filters it out
    MarkAsRenamed(e);
  }
}
```

Usually this works and when a rename is performed, the folder is first marked as renamed in `fsw_Renamed` and then filtered out in the loop by `ExceptThoseMarkedAsRenamed` and not processed as new.

But sometimes the following order occurs:

1. Folder is renamed in Windows Explorer and in the filesystem (while the Loop is holding lock)
2. fsw_Renamed occurs, but cannot obtain the lock
3. The looping thread is still holding lock and picks up the folder as new (it was not marked as renamed yet)
4. The looping thread releases the lock
5. Renamed event occurs, gets the lock, and folder is marked as renamed. But it is already too late since it was already processed as new.

I am having trouble figuring out how to ensure that a renamed folder is never processed as new.

A renamed folder is such folder for which the `Renamed` event **occurred or will occur in near future**, because there is an inherent delay between filesystem change and the `FileSystemWatcher.Renamed` event (and the actual change in filesystem and the event raised are not atomic).

**How to ensure that the change done by fsw_Renamed is always taken into account by the Loop, even if the event occurred while Loop was holding the lock?**

Comment: I can't see all your other code but on the outset, this doesn't look like a very efficient way to deal with the scenario. You look like you'll have HUGE lock contention. Are you able to 'signal' your first thread to deal with the changes (instead of sleep())? I might be missing why you're looping at all.

Comment: the code I have posted is a heavily simplified sample and I am hot having any problems with lock contention. There is no real sleep in the Loop. You are also not answering my question, only commenting on an unrelated issue. I am looping because I need to detect new folders and I need to process also folders which were not handled by FSW (e.g. while the app was not running or it was in suspended state).

Answer (score 1):

You want to process folders, with two different kinds of processing according to whether the folder is new or simply renamed.
You are using an fs monitoring object which fires events when a given folder has been renamed.
You should use a similar monitoring for new folders, and have these events create a task bound to the folder.

The thread catching the events wouldn't have the race condition issue, and would only dispatch new tasks, hence it would not be delayed by a processing and able to deal with new events when they occurs.
The task queue could simply be a list of pairs containing the folder and the task to apply to it.

When a folder is scheduled for processing, any events happening to them should be filtered out by the monitor, by check the task queue to see if the folder is there. It could even change the task or remove it according to other factors (if the folder has been deleted before being processed for instance - perhaps it would be good to monitor that event too).

A task could be something like:

- lock the folder to be processed (this avoid external influences on the folder)
- process it
- mark it as "processed" (take it out of the list)
- unlock it

You cannot keep the renameLock, as it is the thing creating the problem in the first place.
If you cannot lock the folder, perhaps you can move it (it's technically like a rename I suppose) somewhere else to do the processing, and then move it back in place.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692981/c-sharp-blocking-a-folder-from-being-changed-while-processing) deals with the problem of locking folders in C#.

Comment: This will not work. The problem is that before I manage to "lock the folder to be processed", the Loop is already processing it. The problem that I am solving is how to handle the delay between the filesystem change and the FSW Rename event - sometimes the loop jumps directly into the delay.

Comment: I completely redesigned my answer. Indeed I didn't understand the problem initially.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to come back and redesigning the answer! It is not feasible to lock the folder in my case, but the event driven task approach will probably work. The key is to remove the loop and rely more on the Created event, despite I do not trust the FSW that much that I would rely solely on it.

Comment: If you don't trust the FSW class (indeed, SO seems full of questions regarding its reliability), maybe you can implement one based on more fundamentals system calls. I dont have any experience in doing that, so I cannot talk about the feasibility of such an approach. Perhaps something like waiting on a handler on the root folder of the FS, and filter out the irrelevant call returns.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

1. Run the `Loop` method **only** at the startup of your application. Probably before subscribing to the `FileSystemWatcher`.
2. Subscribe to the `FileSystemWatcher.Created` on the directory on which you subscribed to `FileSystemWatcher.Renamed`.
3. Keep the `FileSystemWatcher.Renamed` subscription as is.
4. Remove the lock since the two events should not conflict with each other.

Step 1. will handle directories created/renamed while your application **is not** running.

Step 2. will handle new directories while your application **is** running.

Step 3. will handle renamed directories while your application **is** running.

Comment: thank you for the advice, this is what I will probably end up doing - the Loop should only run after startup and the rest should be event driven