# C# : edit file access control

Tags: c#, security, access-control

hi i am working on c# project and i try to lock a file from being opened , copied or even deleted by using that code :

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
            FileSecurity ds = fi.GetAccessControl();
            ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Authenticated Users",      FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny));
            fi.SetAccessControl(ds);
```

but when i open the file , it is opened and can be deleted , is there anything wrong on my code ?

by the way , that code works perfectly on anywhere but flash drive , i can block editing or copying files from computer , but on flash drive the application is useless .

Comment: Probably here was answer to your question - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432050/how-to-lock-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What filesystem does your flash drive have?  I'm guessing FAT32, rather than NTFS.

FAT32 has no concept of per-file ACLs (or as far as I know, no concept of ACLs whatsoever).

See this article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(WS.10).aspx

> On a FAT or FAT32 volume, you can set permissions for shared folders but not for files and folders within a shared folder. Moreover, share permissions on a FAT or FAT32 volume restrict network access only, not access by users working directly on the computer.

The only option will be to *open* the file in exclusive access mode to prevent others from changing it *while you are reading it*.

See this question (stolen from Vitaliy's comment):

[How to lock file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432050/how-to-lock-file)

The code from the accepted answer:

```
using (FileStream fs = 
       File.Open("MyFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    // use fs
}
```

Comment: correct , it was FAT and i changed it to NTFS and it works fine , thanks