# IOException happening despite thread synchronization C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, ioexception

I have setup 2 event handlers both declared within the same class (let's call it `WrapperClass`): one to save files to a folder and another to send those files to a web api. In the application main thread, I called the two methods at application start-up:

```
// save file to folder:
NewFileEventHandler();
// send file to api:
FileTransporter();
```

`NewFileEventHandler` is defined as below:

```
public void NewFileEventHandler()
{
    SomeEventClass.NewFileEvent +=
         new FileEventHandler(SaveFileToFolder);
}

private void SaveFileToFolder(File file)
{
    FileHelper.SaveFileToFolder(file);
}
```

`FileTransporter` is defined as below, which is where I'm getting the issue with:

```
public void FileTransporter()
{
     FileSystemWatcher newFileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
     newFileWatcher.Path = ConfigurationHelper.applicationRootDirectory;
     newFileWatcher.Filter = "*.txt";
     newFileWatcher.Created +=
     new FileSystemEventHandler(TransportFile);
     newFileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

And the `TransportFile()` is given below:

private void TransportFile(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    lock (_fileTransportLock)
    {
         string[] files = new string[] { };
         files = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationHelper.applicationRootDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
         Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) =>
         {
             bool isHttpTransferSuccess = false;

             isHttpTransferSuccess = FileHelper.SendFileToApi(userid, currentFile);
             if (isHttpTransferSuccess)
             {
                 File.Delete(currentFile);
             }
        });
     }
}
```

However, the line:

throws the exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\myapp\file.txt' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode)
   at FileHelper.SendFileToApi(String userId, String fileLocation)
```

What I don't understand is, because of the `lock` the only possible two processes that can be using this file are the thread that is saving the file and the thread that is trying to send the file to the api. However, my understanding of the `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event is that it triggers when the creation of the file is complete. Which means, the thread that is saving the file should not be using the file by the time `TransportFile()` method try to open the file to send it to api.

Sometimes there are more than one file in the folder (due to missed out emails in the past). The `IOException` is only thrown for the file that was just saved to folder (in other words, the file that raised the `FileSystemWatcher.Created` event. The other files in the folder get cleared as expected. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you are missing here:

1. The event that you are hooking is `FileCreated`. This event is fired (probably unsurprisingly) when the file is created by some other process, *not* when that other process has finished writing the file. What's happening here is that your process is getting notified while the other process is still writing the file, and has an exclusive lock on it. From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The OnCreated event is raised as soon as a file is created. If a file
>   is being copied or transferred into a watched directory, the OnCreated
>   event will be raised immediately, followed by one or more OnChanged
>   events.

2. After the file is created, you loop over all of the files in the directory (not just the file that was just created) and transport all of them. If multiple files are created, the first call to the event will attempt to access any files in the directory (in parallel, in fact), and so even if 1) wasn't an issue, you could have a collision here with another file being written to while processing the event for the first.

The right thing to do here is to loop until you are able to read the file, as specified in the second answer here: [Wait for file to be freed by process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406808/wait-for-file-to-be-freed-by-process)

Comment: Oh I see... Thanks for the explanation. The reason I'm looping over all the files if because I need to make sure the latest file and any other files missed out in previous attempts are cleared. Thanks for the explanation, I will work on this.

Comment: one more thing, is it okay, the way I'm using the lock? The reason why I set that lock is if multiple files were created and more than one events raised, I wanted the subsequent event raised to be handled after completing the current event.

Comment: The lock will prevent that, yes... There are potentially better ways to do it, but that will work.

Comment: if you have time do point me in some of those better ways :) Thank you for your help so far, I can work with this information already.

Comment: Since it looks like you are writing the files yourself, I'd just call the upload method after the file was written (in the `SaveFileToFolder` method). You could have a sweep of the directory after that. Rather than bother with a FSW.

Comment: This is exactly what I started doing :) Thanks very much for the advice. Your explanation greatly simplified my approach!