# UWP/C# - How can I wait for a file to appear before reading it?

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I am writing to a file, then reading it back right after:

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, command, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);   
var readFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(WEB_LOG);
```

However, `GetFileAsync` throws a `FileNotFoundException` because the file hasn't appeared yet. If I use the debugger and wait a little after `WriteTextAsync` finishes, I can see the file appear in the folder and `GetFileAsync` does not throw an exception. How can I wait for the file to be fully written to and appear in the folder so that `GetFileAsync` does not throw an exception?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the Microsoft's docs to be notified when the OS finishes writing a file and I guess the most basic solution is to implement a method that check periodically if the file has been created. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1406853/1817574 ?

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/876513/1817574

Comment: Do you really *have* to save the file and read it back? That is best avoided whenever possible.

Comment: I just realized this issue is not due to UWP, and the code above would probably work well. I have a better understanding of the code I'm working with. What is happening is that a file is created in C:\ drive. UWP can't access it unless using a FilePicker (use of which is not possible for this app), so a Win32 agent is copying the contents of the file into the accessible UWP Known Folders upon reading a command that the UWP app creates and the Win32 agent polls for. My only option I think is to just await a certain amount of time using a Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync?view=winrt-22621) to check if the file is ready. This method returns **null** instead of raising a **FileNotFoundException** if the specified file or folder is not found.

Like this:

```
 var target=  await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.TryGetItemAsync("FileName");

        if (target != null)
        {
            // file is ready
        }
        else 
        {
            //wait and try to get the file again
        }
```

Comment: Ended up working well. Thanks, Roy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function, which will allow you to wait on a particular  file to be available for reading. You have to check if it is not ready then wait...

```
 await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, command, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8); 

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream inputStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    if (inputStream.Length > 0)
                        break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }

var readFile = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(WEB_LOG);
```

Comment: If it’s async `await Task.Delay` should be used instead of `Thread.Sleep`.